# Ag-Grid rowDataChanged not firing properly

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Here is my `onDataChanged()` event. It's plugged into my Ag-Grid HTML. It does fire (3 times) but each time it only thinks there's 1 row being displayed. I'm using the serverSide row model and data coming in from the server is a bit slow, so I think that's the problem. I need to have this event fire when the data is changed though, so I can perform some actions when I have a full list of data. At the moment, again, it only ever thinks there's 1 row being displayed when I see that there are 20 in the list.

```
     onDataChanged: function(event) {
        var count;
        console.log("data changed");
        count = this.gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount();
        console.log(count);
      }
// only ever outputs "1" even though I see 20+ items in the list
```

Because I'm using the serverSide row model, I'm using a serverDatasource to populate the data. Is there another way to detect when data has been changed? Thank you

Comment: Server being slow shouldn't be a problem. I think you are initializing `dataSource` in incorrect manner. Could you share your code on plunk or stackblitz?

Comment: @Paritosh Getting it to work on one of those would be pretty time consuming but here's a pastebin of the code. I use CoffeeScript - here's that file https://pastebin.com/v9SrQLKz, or here's a pastebin of some translated JS I got from an online tool: https://pastebin.com/9CmrZFL7

The main takeaway is that the "works" variable is a list of inventory items. Anything that is like "gridLoadMore" or "gridFetch" or whatever are making calls to the server to fetch data. `this.CreateAgGridDataSource() ` creates the data source to put in with `this.gridOptions.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource)`

Comment: @Dan, did you ever found a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue now